# Generate qrcode and save to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, qr-code

I write this script to generate QRCode then save it to google drive, link in column A and file name in column B (with header):

```
function qrcode() {
  var folderid = Browser.inputBox("Folder ID", "Type or copy/paste the folder ID:",Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderid === "cancel" || folderid == ""){return;}
  var url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&margin=5&data=";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var link = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow).getValues(); 
  var name = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow).getValues();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  var count = 0
  while (count < lastRow-1){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+encodeURIComponent(link[count]));
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200)
    {
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(name[count]+".jpg")
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).createFile(blob);
    }
    count = count + 1
  }
}
```

When the script run, this message appear:
Exception: Request failed for https://api.qrserver.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: en: malformed 'create-qr-code' API request. Please consider the API documentation at http://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/ de: ungültige 'cr... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

But the script is working (i get the result ok)

What wrong with my script???

Comment: `getValues()` returns 2 dimensional aray like `[["sample"],["sample"],,,]`. So when `encodeURIComponent(link[count])` is modified to `encodeURIComponent(link[count][0])`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: any suggestion what the right script is? i am very newbie

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `any suggestion what the right script is? i am very newbie`, unfortunately, I had already proposed it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike oh i see. i've tried your suggestion, and the result is same as mine. the QR Code is made but the error message still appear. thanks anyway.